# Having problems installing jupyter notebook with pip

Tags: python, rust, installation, pip, jupyter

This is the error message I get:

```
ERROR: Cannot install jupyter-server because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    jupyter-core 5.7.1 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.7.0 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.6.1 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.5.1 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.5.0 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.4.0 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.3.2 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.3.1 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.3.0 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.2.0 depends on pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.1.5 depends on pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.1.4 depends on pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.1.3 depends on pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.1.2 depends on pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.1.1 depends on pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.1.0 depends on pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 4.12.0 depends on pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

I have installed jupyter notebook on another laptop, but it was never this complicated. This time the installation of pywinpty asked for rust compiler. Installed it but still not working. This is the entire log:

```
C:\Users\radhe>pip install jupyter notebook
Collecting jupyter
  Using cached jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.7 kB)
Collecting notebook
  Using cached notebook-7.0.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10 kB)
Collecting qtconsole (from jupyter)
  Using cached qtconsole-5.5.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
Collecting jupyter-console (from jupyter)
  Using cached jupyter_console-6.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting nbconvert (from jupyter)
  Using cached nbconvert-7.14.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.7 kB)
Collecting ipykernel (from jupyter)
  Using cached ipykernel-6.29.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.0 kB)
Collecting ipywidgets (from jupyter)
  Using cached ipywidgets-8.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.4 kB)
Collecting jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0 (from notebook)
  Using cached jupyter_server-2.12.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
Collecting jupyterlab-server<3,>=2.22.1 (from notebook)
  Using cached jupyterlab_server-2.25.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.9 kB)
Collecting jupyterlab<5,>=4.0.2 (from notebook)
  Using cached jupyterlab-4.0.10-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (15 kB)
Collecting notebook-shim<0.3,>=0.2 (from notebook)
  Using cached notebook_shim-0.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting tornado>=6.2.0 (from notebook)
  Using cached tornado-6.4.tar.gz (498 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting anyio>=3.1.0 (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached anyio-4.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting argon2-cffi (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached argon2_cffi-23.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.2 kB)
Collecting jinja2 (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached Jinja2-3.1.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.3 kB)
Collecting jupyter-client>=7.4.4 (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached jupyter_client-8.6.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.3 kB)
Collecting jupyter-core!=5.0.*,>=4.12 (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.7.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
Collecting jupyter-events>=0.9.0 (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached jupyter_events-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.7 kB)
Collecting jupyter-server-terminals (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached jupyter_server_terminals-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.6 kB)
Collecting nbformat>=5.3.0 (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached nbformat-5.9.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
Collecting overrides (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached overrides-7.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.7 kB)
Collecting packaging (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
Collecting prometheus-client (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached prometheus_client-0.19.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
Collecting pywinpty (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached pywinpty-2.0.12.tar.gz (27 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pyzmq>=24 (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached pyzmq-25.1.2.tar.gz (1.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting send2trash>=1.8.2 (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Downloading Send2Trash-1.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting terminado>=0.8.3 (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Downloading terminado-0.18.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting traitlets>=5.6.0 (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached traitlets-5.14.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10 kB)
Collecting websocket-client (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Downloading websocket_client-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.9 kB)
Collecting async-lru>=1.0.0 (from jupyterlab<5,>=4.0.2->notebook)
  Using cached async_lru-2.0.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.5 kB)
Collecting jupyter-lsp>=2.0.0 (from jupyterlab<5,>=4.0.2->notebook)
  Using cached jupyter_lsp-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
Collecting babel>=2.10 (from jupyterlab-server<3,>=2.22.1->notebook)
  Downloading Babel-2.14.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
Collecting json5>=0.9.0 (from jupyterlab-server<3,>=2.22.1->notebook)
  Downloading json5-0.9.14-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10 kB)
Collecting jsonschema>=4.18.0 (from jupyterlab-server<3,>=2.22.1->notebook)
  Downloading jsonschema-4.21.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.0 kB)
Collecting requests>=2.31 (from jupyterlab-server<3,>=2.22.1->notebook)
  Downloading requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting beautifulsoup4 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (142 kB)
Collecting bleach!=5.0.0 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached bleach-6.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (30 kB)
Collecting defusedxml (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting jupyterlab-pygments (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached jupyterlab_pygments-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.4 kB)
Collecting markupsafe>=2.0 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached MarkupSafe-2.1.3.tar.gz (19 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting mistune<4,>=2.0.3 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached mistune-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.7 kB)
Collecting nbclient>=0.5.0 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached nbclient-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.8 kB)
Collecting pandocfilters>=1.4.1 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached pandocfilters-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.7 kB)
Collecting pygments>=2.4.1 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached pygments-2.17.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.6 kB)
Collecting tinycss2 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached tinycss2-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting comm>=0.1.1 (from ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached comm-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
Collecting debugpy>=1.6.5 (from ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached debugpy-1.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.1 kB)
Collecting ipython>=7.23.1 (from ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached ipython-8.20.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.9 kB)
Collecting matplotlib-inline>=0.1 (from ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached matplotlib_inline-0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl (9.4 kB)
Collecting nest-asyncio (from ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached nest_asyncio-1.5.9-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
Collecting psutil (from ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached psutil-5.9.7.tar.gz (498 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting widgetsnbextension~=4.0.9 (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Using cached widgetsnbextension-4.0.9-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
Collecting jupyterlab-widgets~=3.0.9 (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Using cached jupyterlab_widgets-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.1 kB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit>=3.0.30 (from jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.43-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.5 kB)
Collecting qtpy>=2.4.0 (from qtconsole->jupyter)
  Using cached QtPy-2.4.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (12 kB)
Collecting idna>=2.8 (from anyio>=3.1.0->jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Downloading idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.9 kB)
Collecting sniffio>=1.1 (from anyio>=3.1.0->jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Downloading sniffio-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting six>=1.9.0 (from bleach!=5.0.0->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting webencodings (from bleach!=5.0.0->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting decorator (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached decorator-5.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.1 kB)
Collecting jedi>=0.16 (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached jedi-0.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (22 kB)
Collecting stack-data (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached stack_data-0.6.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (18 kB)
Collecting colorama (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting attrs>=22.2.0 (from jsonschema>=4.18.0->jupyterlab-server<3,>=2.22.1->notebook)
  Downloading attrs-23.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.5 kB)
Collecting jsonschema-specifications>=2023.03.6 (from jsonschema>=4.18.0->jupyterlab-server<3,>=2.22.1->notebook)
  Downloading jsonschema_specifications-2023.12.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting referencing>=0.28.4 (from jsonschema>=4.18.0->jupyterlab-server<3,>=2.22.1->notebook)
  Downloading referencing-0.32.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.7 kB)
Collecting rpds-py>=0.7.1 (from jsonschema>=4.18.0->jupyterlab-server<3,>=2.22.1->notebook)
  Downloading rpds_py-0.17.1.tar.gz (24 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.8.2 (from jupyter-client>=7.4.4->jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting platformdirs>=2.5 (from jupyter-core!=5.0.*,>=4.12->jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached platformdirs-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (11 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of jupyter-core to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting jupyter-core!=5.0.*,>=4.12 (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.6.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.5.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.3.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
INFO: pip is still looking at multiple versions of jupyter-core to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.1.5-py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. See https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/backtracking for guidance. If you want to abort this run, press Ctrl + C.
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-5.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (92 kB)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (89 kB)
Collecting jupyter-client>=7.4.4 (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached jupyter_client-8.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.3 kB)
Collecting qtconsole (from jupyter)
  Using cached qtconsole-5.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
Collecting jupyter-console (from jupyter)
  Using cached jupyter_console-6.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting ipykernel (from jupyter)
  Using cached ipykernel-6.28.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.0 kB)
Collecting nbconvert (from jupyter)
  Using cached nbconvert-7.14.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.7 kB)
Collecting jupyterlab<5,>=4.0.2 (from notebook)
  Downloading jupyterlab-4.0.9-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (15 kB)
Collecting jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0 (from notebook)
  Using cached jupyter_server-2.12.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.12.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.12.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.12.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.12.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.11.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.11.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.10.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.10.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.9.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.6 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.6 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.8.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.6 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.7.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.6 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.7.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.6 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.7.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.6 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.6 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.5 kB)
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (366 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 366.8/366.8 kB 1.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading jupyter_server-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (366 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 366.7/366.7 kB 1.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
ERROR: Cannot install jupyter-server because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    jupyter-core 5.7.1 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.7.0 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.6.1 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.5.1 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.5.0 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.4.0 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.3.2 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.3.1 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.3.0 depends on pywin32>=300; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.2.0 depends on pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.1.5 depends on pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.1.4 depends on pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.1.3 depends on pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.1.2 depends on pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.1.1 depends on pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 5.1.0 depends on pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
    jupyter-core 4.12.0 depends on pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

Comment: Try to make a fresh virtual enviorement in your project directory, and try to re-install again.
[Creating virtual environement guide](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `jupyter` from your list of packages. Just install the notebook only: `pip install notebook`.

`jupyter` is a meta-package, but PyPI shows it to be from 2015, and never updated. It's Python tags go up to only 3.4, so I consider it outdated.

See also the [installation instructions](https://jupyter.org/install) at the Jupyter webpage:

> ## JupyterLab
>
> Install JupyterLab with pip:
>
> ```
> pip install jupyterlab
> ```
>
> Note: If you install JupyterLab with conda or mamba, we recommend using the conda-forge channel.
>
> Once installed, launch JupyterLab with:
>
> ```
> jupyter lab
> ```
>
> ## Jupyter Notebook
>
> Install the classic Jupyter Notebook with:
>
> ```
> pip install notebook
> ```
>
> To run the notebook:
>
> ```
> jupyter notebook
> ```